# Building Elasticsearch 7.6.0 on Windows

Tags: elasticsearch, gradle, docker-compose

my basic goal: building elasticsearch 7.6.0 from source. Tried now for hours with different errors. So maybe you've an idea.

I'm building on Windows, gradle and Docker are also installed on that machine. When trying to start the build with "gradlew run" or "gradlew assemble" I always get into this error:

*Tests for :distribution:docker require docker-compose at /usr/local/bin/docker-compose or /usr/bin/docker-compose but none could be found so these will be skipped*

Any ideas?

Comment: its searching for docker-compose which comes by default with windows docker installation, can you check if docker-compose is added to your environment path.

Comment: Yes, docker-compose works fine and is already in the environment path. Nonetheless, I get this error message.